# drawing a rectangle on line chart in d3js and nvd3

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to draw a rectangle over the bottom region of the chart, x from 0 to 7, y from 100'000 to 200'00.
The d3js coordinate is different from the nvd3 so I need to figure out how to convert the coordinates.
You can see my attempt. The rectangle is the red one.
Can someone guide me with this please?

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.5/nv.d3.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.5/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function draw(){
   var raw_data = [{"values": [{"y": 349189.0, "x": 0}, {"y": 379731.0, "x": 1}, {"y": 313599.0, "x": 2}, {"y": 349650.0, "x": 3}, {"y": 584350.0, "x": 4}, {"y": 579617.0, "x": 5}, {"y": 566992.0, "x": 6}, {"y": 436520.0, "x": 7}], "key": "Kv3.4.78", "yAxis": "1"}, {"values": [{"y": 248515.0, "x": 0}, {"y": 254820.0, "x": 1}, {"y": 204568.0, "x": 2}, {"y": 131445.0, "x": 3}, {"y": 75468.0, "x": 4}, {"y": 75958.0, "x": 5}, {"y": 69591.0, "x": 6}, {"y": 105540.0, "x": 7}], "key": "Kv3.4.77", "yAxis": "1"}, {"values": [{"y": 402385.0, "x": 0}, {"y": 445230.0, "x": 1}, {"y": 389273.0, "x": 2}, {"y": 407087.0, "x": 3}, {"y": 793282.0, "x": 4}, {"y": 791361.0, "x": 5}, {"y": 753506.0, "x": 6}, {"y": 630189.0, "x": 7}], "key": "Kv3.4.135", "yAxis": "1"}, {"values": [{"y": 291251.0, "x": 0}, {"y": 327427.0, "x": 1}, {"y": 268603.0, "x": 2}, {"y": 282463.0, "x": 3}, {"y": 476328.0, "x": 4}, {"y": 467403.0, "x": 5}, {"y": 451372.0, "x": 6}, {"y": 421342.0, "x": 7}], "key": "Kv3.4.79", "yAxis": "1"}];
   var qc_type = 'aligned';
   var data = raw_data;
   nv.addGraph(function() {
       var chart = nv.models.lineChart();
       chart.margin({
           top: 30,
           right: 60,
           bottom: 100,
           left: 100
       });

       chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.02f'));
       chart.showLegend(true).useVoronoi(false);
       d3.select('#qc_overtime_id svg')
           .datum(data)
           .transition().duration(500)
           .attr('width', 1300)
           .attr('height', 400)
           .call(chart);
   });
   
var svg = d3.select('#qc_overtime_id svg')
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", 400)
 .attr("height", 200);
 
 var rec_data = [{x1: 300, x2: 10000, y1: 150, y2: 300}];
 var rects = svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(rec_data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", d=> d.x1)
  .attr("y", d=> d.y1)
  .attr("width", d=> d.x2 - d.x1)
  .attr("height", d=> d.y2 - d.y1)
  .attr("fill", "red")
  .attr("opacity", 0.5);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="draw();">
  <div id="qc_overtime_id">
    <svg style="width:1300px;height:550px;"></svg>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**update**
Here is another example with the help of the solution:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.5/nv.d3.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.5/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function draw(){
  data = [{"values":[
{"x": 0, "y": 0},{"x": 1, "y": 1219000},{"x": 2, "y": 1035409},{"x": 3, "y": 1305046},{"x": 4, "y": 2060407},{"x": 5, "y": 583834},{"x": 6, "y": 1111078},{"x": 7, "y": 987715},{"x": 8, "y": 1044967},{"x": 9, "y": 1026166},{"x": 10, "y": 1038733},{"x": 11, "y": 1011022},{"x": 12, "y": 1048301},{"x": 13, "y": 1079529},{"x": 14, "y": 1232463},{"x": 15, "y": 1004553},{"x": 16, "y": 1050922},{"x": 17, "y": 219877},{"x": 18, "y": 909885}], "key": "Kv3.4.79", "yAxis": "1"}];
 
   var labels = [];
   for(ind in data[0].values){
      labels.push("abcd" + ind);
   }

   nv.addGraph(function() {
       var chart = nv.models.lineChart();
       chart.margin({
           top: 30,
           right: 60,
           bottom: 100,
           left: 100
       });

       chart.xAxis
           .rotateLabels(-25).tickFormat(function(d) {
               return labels[d];
           });
       chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.02f'));

       chart.showLegend(true).useVoronoi(false);
       svg = d3.select('#chart svg')
           .datum(data)
           .transition().duration(500)
           .attr('width', 1300)
           .attr('height', 400)
           .call(chart);

         var rec_data = {x1: 0, x2: labels.length, y1: 700000, y2: 1000000};
         d3.select('#chart svg')
          .append( 'rect' )
            .attr("x", chart.margin().left + chart.xAxis.scale()( rec_data.x1 ) )
            .attr("y", chart.yAxis.scale()( rec_data.y1 ) - chart.margin().bottom - chart.margin().top )
            .attr("width", chart.xAxis.scale()( rec_data.x2 ) - chart.xAxis.scale()( rec_data.x1 ) )
            .attr("height", chart.yAxis.scale()( rec_data.y1 ) - chart.yAxis.scale()( rec_data.y2 ) )
            .attr("fill", "green")
            .attr("opacity", 0.3);

   });
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="draw();">
  <div id="chart">
    <svg style="width:1300px;height:550px;"></svg>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So why do you make a separate coordinate system for that rectangle? why not use just put it into the same one as the original graph, so you can reuse the nvd3 scaling function?

Comment: I want to use the same but I don't know how. I've tried adding the data method right after the original call(chart) but it does not draw anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure, how nvd3 composes its line chart (the y-value scale seems strange), but the following should work for you.

So what I basically did:

- I moved the rectangle generation inside the nvd3 callback, so I have access to the `chart` object.
- I used the nvd3 scaling functions to find the correct coordinates for the rectangle.
- I omitted the data-binding here, as you only have one rectangle and it saved me a few lines of code ,-)

The documentation for nvd3 is rather bad, so I had to inspect the objects and their methods by hand, but it seems this is an officially sanctioned way to add additional elements.

```js
function draw(){
   var raw_data = [{"values": [{"y": 349189.0, "x": 0}, {"y": 379731.0, "x": 1}, {"y": 313599.0, "x": 2}, {"y": 349650.0, "x": 3}, {"y": 584350.0, "x": 4}, {"y": 579617.0, "x": 5}, {"y": 566992.0, "x": 6}, {"y": 436520.0, "x": 7}], "key": "Kv3.4.78", "yAxis": "1"}, {"values": [{"y": 248515.0, "x": 0}, {"y": 254820.0, "x": 1}, {"y": 204568.0, "x": 2}, {"y": 131445.0, "x": 3}, {"y": 75468.0, "x": 4}, {"y": 75958.0, "x": 5}, {"y": 69591.0, "x": 6}, {"y": 105540.0, "x": 7}], "key": "Kv3.4.77", "yAxis": "1"}, {"values": [{"y": 402385.0, "x": 0}, {"y": 445230.0, "x": 1}, {"y": 389273.0, "x": 2}, {"y": 407087.0, "x": 3}, {"y": 793282.0, "x": 4}, {"y": 791361.0, "x": 5}, {"y": 753506.0, "x": 6}, {"y": 630189.0, "x": 7}], "key": "Kv3.4.135", "yAxis": "1"}, {"values": [{"y": 291251.0, "x": 0}, {"y": 327427.0, "x": 1}, {"y": 268603.0, "x": 2}, {"y": 282463.0, "x": 3}, {"y": 476328.0, "x": 4}, {"y": 467403.0, "x": 5}, {"y": 451372.0, "x": 6}, {"y": 421342.0, "x": 7}], "key": "Kv3.4.79", "yAxis": "1"}];
   var qc_type = 'aligned';
   var data = raw_data;
   nv.addGraph(function() {
       var chart = nv.models.lineChart();
       chart.margin({
           top: 30,
           right: 60,
           bottom: 100,
           left: 100
       });

       chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.02f'));
       chart.showLegend(true).useVoronoi(false);
       d3.select('#qc_overtime_id svg')
           .datum(data)
           .transition().duration(500)
           .attr('width', 1300)
           .attr('height', 400)
           .call(chart);

       var rec_data = {x1: 0, x2: 7, y1: 100000, y2: 200000};
       d3.select('#qc_overtime_id svg')
          .append( 'rect' )
            .attr("x", chart.margin().left + chart.xAxis.scale()( rec_data.x1 ) )
            .attr("y", chart.yAxis.scale()( rec_data.y1 ) - chart.margin().top )
            .attr("width", chart.xAxis.scale()( rec_data.x2 ) - chart.xAxis.scale()( rec_data.x1 ) )
            .attr("height", chart.yAxis.scale()( rec_data.y1 ) - chart.yAxis.scale()( rec_data.y2 ) )
            .attr("fill", "red")
            .attr("opacity", 0.5);

   });
}
draw();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.5/nv.d3.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.5/nv.d3.css"  rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="qc_overtime_id">
  <svg style="width:1300px;height:550px;"></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried some other lineCharts with different scales and x labels and the y axis became very off so the y axis transformation in your solution is sometimes wrong.

Comment: It seems that chart.margin().top is inaccurate.

Comment: Like I said - official documentation is missing, so I had to fiddle around. The general idea is just to use `chart.xAxis.scale()` (or `yAxis`) to transform your coordinates. Any offsets etc have to be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: I totally agree that it's lack of documentation. Nevertheless, I commented to indicate that I'm observing the problem.

Comment: Can you provide a small fiddle? Maybe with that we can find a common solution for all graphs.

Comment: Sure. I've added a new snippet.